# What's the difference between distributed hashtable technology and the bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: hashtable, distributed, bitcoin, dht, blockchain

This question could go into a bitcoin forum but I am trying to understand from a programming point of view.

There are technologies used for distributed storage, like distributed hashtables (say kademlia or similar). How is the bitcoin blockchain different from distributed hashtables? Or is maybe distributed hashtable technology underpinning the bitcoin blockchain? Or why is the bitcoin blockchain hailed as such a breakthrough compared to DHT?

Comment: @jww thansk for your comment. Appreciate your intentions but I frankly do not agree. I am a developer, and DHT is a programming technique.This question is nearly 3 years old, at a time when my knowledge of blockchain was pretty limited. As a developer, I wanted to understand these development concepts better. By now, I wouldn't put that question like that. But the answer helped at that time, so I'd vote to keep it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Distributed Hash Table

A DHT is simply a [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database) distributed accross a number of
nodes in a network. The keys are distributed among nodes with a
deterministic algorithm. Each node is responsible for a portion of
the hash table.

A routing algorithm allows to perform requests in the hash table
without knowing every node of the network.

For exemple in the [Chord
DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28peer-to-peer%29) —which is relatively simple DHT implementation— each
node is assigned an identifier and is responsible of keys which
are closer to its identifier.

Imagine there is 4 nodes that have identifiers: 2a6c, 7811, a20f, e9c3
The data with the identifier 2c92 will be stored on the node 2a6c.

Imagine now that you only know the node 7811 and you are looking
for the data with the identifier eabc.

You ask the node 7811 for the data eabc. 7811 doesn't have it so
it ask the node e9c3 wich send it to node 7811 which send it back
to you.

A clever algorithm allows to find data in O(log(N))
jumps. Without storing the entire routing table of the
network (the addresses of each nodes). Basically you ask the
closest node to the data identifier you know wich itself asks the
closest node it knows and so on reducing the size of the jump at
each step.

A DHT is very scalable because the data are uniformly distributed
among nodes and lookup time generally grows in O(log(N)).

### Blockchain

A blockchain is also a distributed data structure but its purpose
is completely different.

Think of it as a history, or a ledger. The purpose is to store a
continuously-growing list of record  without the possibility of
tampering and revision.

It is mainly used in the bitcoin currency system for keeping
track of transactions. Its property of being tamper-proof let everybody
know the exact balance of an account by knowing its history of
transaction.

In a blockchain, each node of the network stores the full data.
So it is absolutely not the same idea as the DHT in which data
are divided among nodes.  Every new entry in the blockchain must
be validated by a process called mining whose details are out of the scope of this answer but this process insure [consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)) of the
data.

The two structures are both distributed data structure but serve
different purposes. DHT aims to provide an efficient (in term of
lookup time and storage footprint) structure to divide data on a
network and blockchain aims to provide a tamper-proof data
structure.

Answer (score 0):

In computing, a hash table (hash map) is a data structure which implements an associative array abstract data type, a structure that can map keys to values. A hash table uses a hash function to compute an index into an array of buckets or slots, from which the desired value can be found.
 but block chain is
a digital ledger in which transactions made in bitcoin or another cryptocurrency are recorded chronologically and publicly.